# Bootstrap: Can't style navbar elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap's [navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp):
It has the following structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <!--<div class="container">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOME TITLE</a>
        </div>-->

        <div class="navbar-header" align="center">
            <a class="navbar-brand shortcuts" href="#">Subtitle</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mine lis">
                                    
               <li><a href="second.jsp">Link1</a></li>
                                    
                                    
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">List of links</a>
                                    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">SLink1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">SLink2</a></li>
                     </ul>
               </li>

               <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   

     </ul>
</nav>
```

And I have a main document that includes the navigation:

```
     <body>
       <header>
                <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
                <jsp:include page="navbar.jsp"/>
       </header>  
       ...
```

I need to add some extra style to the links of navigation, so I tried:

```
<style>
     a {color:red;}
    
</style>
```

and

```
<style>
      .navbar a {color:yellow;}
</style>
```

But neither works! What is the problem?

EDIT: The `<style>..</style>` part is included in `<html><head>...</head>`.

Comment: have you tried with !imporant ?

Comment: To override the basic css of bootstrap you have to use !important, as Marko said.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked for me, didn't know about that thing, Make the answer and I mark it as solved.

Comment: @Marko give the answer so op can accept. working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bg7fh21L/

Comment: @parsecer but keep in mind, one should !important only when he needed most or else try to avoid !important.

Comment: @Leo the lion, OK, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have mentioned in comments, you need to override bootstrap's css, so using `!important` applies new CSS rules and answers your question :)

Also, make sure you don't use !important tag too often, it's not a good practise

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bootstrap is using the following CSS to style the link:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a
```

Your CSS tries to overwrite that, but it fails because it has a lower [specifity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

To fix you could:

- Change your styles to be more specific
- Make changes to bootstrap itself (they have a customizer available

Comment: He isn't including style inside the header.

Comment: Or (bad practice) use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override bootstrap class just add class or id to your parent container and prefix your styles with it, that should do. CSS allways picks up most specific selector available if they are the same then it takes last option